# The XMLHttp Post Request is not connecting to the java class after the css has been changed

Tags: html, css, post, xmlhttprequest, http-post

The form in the Admin.html page is used to update the database. It was working properly until we changed the styles.css file. Now it is not working anymore and I am not able to figure out where it is going wrong.

The Admin.html creates a XMLHttpRequest (Post request), which then goes to the Admin Resource java class where the database is updated. Part of the code is attached to this question.

This is the function in Admin.html:

```
 function formElements() {
        let tableName = document.getElementById("Table_name");
        let columnName = document.getElementById("Column_name");
        if (document.getElementById('Column_name').value.length == 0) {
            columnName.value = '2';
        }
        let value = document.getElementById("Value");
        if (document.getElementById('Value').value.length == 0) {
            value.value = '2';
        }
        let conditionColumn = document.getElementById("ConditionColumn");

        let condition = document.getElementById("Condition");
        if (document.getElementById('ConditionColumn').value.length == 0) {
            conditionColumn.value = '2';
        }
        if (document.getElementById('Condition').value.length == 0) {
            condition.value = 'a';
        }
        var option = document.getElementById('Actions');
        var selectedOption = option.options[option.selectedIndex];

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/Kadaster5/rest/request?tablename=' + tableName.value + '&columnname=' +
            columnName.value + '&value=' + value.value + '&conditionClm=' + conditionColumn.value + '&condition='
            + condition.value + '&option=' + selectedOption.value, true);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () { //TODO: check if this is needed
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                const objects = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
                //TODO: check what to do here and change accordingly
                if (objects.includes("success")) {
                    window.location.href = "admin.html"
                } else {
                    alert("Request rejected");
                }
            }
            ;
        }
        xhttp.send();
    }
```

This is the styles.css file:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.backgroundImage{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7), rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), url("https://st2.depositphotos.com/31006582/46187/v/950/depositphotos_461870688-stock-illustration-bright-grey-vector-background-map.jpg?forcejpeg=true");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;

}

.header {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.text-box{
    width: 87%;
    color: #eeeeee;
    position: center;
    top: 90%;
    left: 100%;
    padding-left: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

/*Navigation bar*/

nav {
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

nav img {
    width: 150px;
}

.nav-links {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-links ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
}

.nav-links ul li a {
    color: #c0c0c0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links ul li::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #2e96e7;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

/*Search bar*/

.searchbar {
    width: 78%;
    height: 10vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: center;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 300px;
}

.search-bar{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 60px;
    padding: 1px 20px;
    backdrop-filter: blur(4px) saturate(180%);
    margin: auto;
}

.search-bar input{
    background: transparent;
    flex: 1;
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    padding: 24px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d5d5da;
}

.search-bar button image{
    width: 40px;
}

.search-bar button{
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background: rgba(168, 168, 168, 0.7);
    cursor: pointer;
}

/*Filter Buttons*/

.education{
    padding-top: 160px;
    position: center;
    left: 100%;
}
.courses{
    padding-top: 160px;
    position: center;
    left: 100%;
}

.body{
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    background: #23242a;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.dropdown{
    min-height: 15em;
    position: relative;
    margin: 2em;
}

.dropdown *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.select{
    background: #2a2f3b;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    border: 2px #2a2f3b solid;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background 0.3s;
}

.select-clicked{
    border: 2px #26489a solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0.8em #26489a;
}

.select:hover{
    background: #323741;
}

.caret{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 6px solid #fff;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.caret-rotate{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.selected-menu{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0.2em 0.5em;
    background: #323741;
    border: 1px #363a43 solid;
    box-shadow: 0 0.5em 1em rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    color: #9fa5b5;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3em;
    left: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.2s;
    z-index: 1;
}

.selected-menu li{
    padding: 0.7em 0.5em;
    margin: 0.3em 0;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.selected-menu li:hover{
    background: #2a2d35;
}

.active{
    background: #23242a;
}

.selected-menu-open{
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

.results{
    font-family:  'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2em;
    position:relative;
}

.navbar .nav-links {
    color: #445373;
    font-size: 1.1em;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav .nav-item::after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: lightblue;
    content: "";
    height: 4px;
    transition: all 0.5s
}

/*Map*/

#map {
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-left: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    width: 900px;
    position: center;
    top: 30px;
    left: 185px;
}

/* About page */

.image img{
    width: 1400px;
    height:500px;
    position:center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text p{
    margin:0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family:  'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2em;
}

.text{
    margin: 70px;
}

/* Contact Page */

.contact-form{
    width:100%;
    height:50vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: center;
}
form1{
    background-position: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width:90%;
    max-width: 600px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
form1 h1{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 800;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
form1 input, form1 textarea{
    border:0;
    margin:10px 0;
    padding:20px;
    outline:none;
    background: #efefef;
    font-size: 16px;
}

form1 button{
    padding:15px;
    background: #3a628c;
    font-size: 18px;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5em;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #355e86, rgb(68, 83, 115));
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

form{
    background-color: white;
    width:90%;
    height:55px;
    display: flex;
}
form input{
    flex:1;
    outline:none;
}

form button{
    padding: 10px 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.image img{
    width: 1400px;
    height:500px;
    position:center;
    padding-left: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.text p{
    margin:0px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 2em;
    color: #eeeeee;
}
.text{
    margin: 70px;
}

.submit {
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5em;
    color: #fff;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #355e86, rgb(68, 83, 115));
    border: 0;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    margin-left: 35%;
    font-size: 13px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

/* type Of Education */

.typeOfEducation{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 100px;
}

h2{
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

p1{
    color: #777;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row{
    margin-top: 5%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.column{
    flex-basis: 31%;
    background: #fff3f3;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    padding: 20px 12px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.column:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.information{
    width: 90%;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: center;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    /*transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

h4{
    font-size: 40px;
}

p2{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    #primary { width:67%; }
    #secondary { width:30%; margin-left:3%;}
}

/*Redirect Signup*/
.container{
    position: center;
}

.main {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 7em auto;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 11px 35px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
}

.main h1{
    padding-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: center;
}

/* Information Values */
.userFilters{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    width: 400px;
    height: 285px;
    margin: 7em auto;
    border-radius: 1.5em;
    box-shadow: 0px 11px 35px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14);
    position: absolute;
    right: 200px;
    top: 550px;
}

.userFilters h6{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-weight: 650;
    font-size: 25px;

}

.userFilters p{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.userFilters button{
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 35px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    background: #323741;
    font-size: 16px;
    border:0;
    outline:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5em;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
    text-align: center;

}
```

This is the Java code and this is how it is linked to the java class:

```
@Path("/request")
public class AdminResource {
   
    @POST
    //@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
    public void editTable(@QueryParam("tablename") String tableName, @QueryParam("columnname") String columnName,
                          @QueryParam("value") String value, @QueryParam("conditionClm") String conditionClm,  @QueryParam("condition") String condition,
                          @QueryParam("option") String option) {
```

Somehow the java class doesn't run even though the post method is sent properly. I use XMLHttpRequests in other parts of my code for Post and Get and those work perfectly fine.